# How to hide source code of django from user?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I know my question title is a little confusing , but i want to do this : 
I have a project that's include these things :

1- A landscape page with html,css,...

2- A Django Admin-Panel for a mysql database .

I'm using a VPS (Virtual Private Server) , and this VPS have not required disk space , i want to use Django admin-panel in local and give it to my employer , but i dont want to give the source code to him , is there any way to hide the source code from my employer but still give him the django admin panel to use on his own computer ?

Answer (score -1):

If you're on the same network and not running Django behind a VM, you can run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0.0`. Your employer will be able to access your Django admin via your internal IP:80 (or whatever port you choose to use).

Alternatively you can route your ports and firewall to your local IP port.

Comment: How about use a network cable to connect with employer's computer with yours?@T.Pool